# how to convert Laravel 5.1/PHP website into ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc, laravel-5.1

I have a complete working Website in Laravel 5.1 and want to Migrate the entire code into ASP.NET MVC 5.x. Is there any easy way to do this? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer **NO**.

Long answer:

1. Learn ASP.net if you don't already know it
2. Code the website according to what you need

**Note:** There is no copy-paste solution, if that's what your looking for. I don't think anyone will create something to 'translate' a laravel (php) to asp.net

There are options to help you along the way:

1.[Migrating from PHP to ASP.NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479002.aspx)

2.[Migration assistants](http://www.asp.net/downloads/archived-v11/migration-assistants/php-to-aspnet/overview)

3.[Online conversion](http://www.me-u.com/php-asp/)

As you can see there are helpers, but I wouldn't rely on them. As you might already know mvc works with different folders, controllers, models, views etc. The conversion tools won't exactly know how to deal with them, so you will have to edit them afterwards, which might take you more time to get a grip on how and what was converted in stead of just coding it all over.

So to "convert" a laravel website it would at least require that you convert **all** files in your laravel project folder. Just thinking about it, I wouldn't want to go that route.

Comment: I was searching the same, Thanks